# ColorScale coloring two values same color

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working with `d3`. I am using `d3.scale.quantize()` to create a `colorScale`. However, it colors two values, `0` and `1`, in the same color.
Any ideas where the problem could be?

```
var extent = d3.extent(collection.features, function(d) {
    return d.properties.ausfaelle;
});
```

A `console.log(extent[0])` and `console.log(extend[1])` returns `0` and `27`.

```
x = 9
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
  .domain([extent[0], extent[1]])
  .range(colorbrewer.OrRd[x]);

var myData= paths
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colorScale(d.properties.value);
  });
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. As you have only 9 colours and 28 values, you'll have the **same** color for `0, 1, 2`, then `3, 4, 5`, then `6, 7, 8`... and, at the end, you'll have the same colour for **four** values: 24, 25, 26 and 27.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ah, that makes sense. I wrongly assumed that 0 will be colored in its "own" color... where that assumption came from

Comment: Well, you can use a linear scale with two colors in the range. That way, you'll have different colours, in a gradient. But, right now, I can tell you that the behaviour you're seeing here is the expected behaviour of a quantize scale.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Ill read into the scales and how they work. Thank you :)